# os.rename not changing file extension in windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x

I have a simple Python 3's script that rename all files in a folder, in the shell it shows the new name applied correctly, but when I go to the folder in windows, the files does not have any extension.

i.e: In python I rename somefile to: "newname.jpg", but on windows it is only "newname", without extension. I guess this is more a Windows 10's problem than a Python's problem.

This is the code:

```
import os
from os import listdir

i = 0
dir = "./PHOTO GALLERY 1"

for archivo in listdir(dir):
    i=i+1
    if i<10:
        j="0"+str(i)
    else:
         j=str(i)   
    print ("Nombre original: " + archivo)
    os.rename(dir + "/" + archivo, dir + "/" + "photogallery1_" + j)
    print ("Nombre nuevo: " + "photogallery1_" + j + ".jpg")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're leaving off the file extension:

```
os.rename(dir + "/" + archivo, dir + "/" + "photogallery1_" + j)
```

should be

```
os.rename(dir + "/" + archivo, dir + "/" + "photogallery1_" + j + ".jpg")
```

like in your print statement.